# Validate child input components on submit with Vee-Validate

Tags: vue.js

I'm currently trying to create a Registration form with multiple "Input Field" components which all require validating once Submit has been pressed. They all currently validate on their own accord when the text within is changed but I'm finding it difficult to make a global call to all input fields to validate all. What I am trying to achieve is the following: http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/examples#validate-form but the validateAll() method has no fields attached to it.

I tried populating validateAll() with email & confirm_email which got me the result I wanted, but the error messages would not show next to the fields.

Any help would be much appreciated!

ValidatedInputField.vue:

```
<template>
   <div class="form-control" v-bind:class="{ errorPrompt : errors.has(name) }">
      <label v-bind:for="name">* {{as}}</label>
      <input ref="input" v-bind:value="_value" @input="updateValue($event.target.value)" v-validate v-bind:data-vv-rules="rules" v-bind:name="name" />
      <span v-bind:v-show="'errors.has(' + name +')'">{{ errors.first(name) }}</span>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
  props: ['name', 'rules', 'as', 'value'],
  methods: {
  updateValue(value) {
     this._value = this.value;
     this.$emit('input', value);
  }
  },
  computed: {
     _value() { return this.value; }
  }
};
</script>
```

Register.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <Card blueHeader="true" title="Register">
      <ValidatedInputField v-model="email" name="email" rules="required|email" as="Email" />
      <ValidatedInputField v-model="confirm_email" name="confirm_email" rules="required|email" as="Confirm Email" />
      <ValidatedInputField name="company" rules="required" as="Company" />
      <InputField name="company_website" as="Company Website" />
      <ValidatedInputField name="first_name" rules="required" as="First Name" />
      <ValidatedInputField name="last_name" rules="required" as="Last Name" />
      <ValidatedInputField name="address_1" rules="required" as="Address 1" />
      <InputField name="address_2" as="Address 2" />
      <ValidatedInputField name="city" rules="required" as="City" />
      <ValidatedInputField name="zip" rules="required" as="Zip/Postal Code" />
    </Card>

    <Card blueHeader="true" title="Terms & Conditions">
      <button v-on:click="submitForm()">Submit</button>
    </Card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ValidatedInputField from './components/ValidatedInputField';
import InputField from './components/InputField';

module.exports = {
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      this.$validator.validateAll();
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      email: '',
      confirm_email: ''
    };
  },
  components: {
    ValidatedInputField,
    InputField
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly. But to make the call globally, you will have to emit an event on clicking the button and instruct each template to act upon that event. The action for each template should be to 'this.$validator.validateAll()', because 'this' will refer to that specific template.

You can do that by creating a named instance ('bus'). Create that before creating the instance.

```
var bus = new Vue({});
```

Use that to emit from the template:

```
bus.$emit('validate_all');
```

and to catch in a template:

```
created: function() {
   var vm = this;
   bus.$on('validate_all', function() {
      vm.$validator.validateAll()
   });
}
```

Now all fields should have been validated and all error messages should show.
Good Luck!

Comment: Works great with Vuejs 2 and VeeValidate 2.

Comment: Great explanation @hugo-wijdeveld! However how to proceed with the submit in the parent component, since it does not have the children errors object?

Comment: Basically I would handle this by having the component emit and have the main instance catch. For instance: you can have the component emit a boolean indicating that there are or there aren't any errors. Then the main instance can decide whether it is OK to submit. But you can be even more verbose and emit the complete error object, so that the main instance can give the user a hint as to where the error took place.

Comment: Another way to do this is to make the parent call the child validators directly, without using an event bus. The answer here provides that solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43472878/398513

Comment: This maybe helpful https://medium.com/@logaretm/authoring-validatable-custom-vue-input-components-1583fcc68314

Answer (score 8):

I have a similar setup, I tried the bus solution with the events, didn't get it working. I however used the Provider/Injector pattern as defined in the specs of v-validate.

So in the top most parent, add this line of code (mind it is TYPESCRIPT !)

```
 @Provide('validator') $validator = this.$validator;
```

And in every child/grandchilds add this line of code:

```
@Inject('validator') $validator: any;
```

Now you can do this in your parent, and I will gather all errors from all components with the validator injector. (see specs: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/api/errorbag.html#api)

```
 if (this.$validator.errors.any()) {
      // Prevent the form from submitting
      e.preventDefault();
    }
```

I have a sort-a-like answer in post; [vee-validate error object - _vm.errors is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162865/vee-validate-error-object-vm-errors-is-undefined/47351643#47351643)

grtz

Comment: Excellent answer. Up voted. Hard to find help resources on vuejs+typescript. Please let me know if you have any good ones.

Comment: Hey @AntonK, i only saw this comment of you right now, there are indeed not that much resources about vue in combination with typescript, but here are some repos we follow: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue and https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli .. we are migrating our projects to the vue cli to stay ahead of all new development (also migrate your projects to webpack 4/typescript > 2.9), and we are eager waiting for VUE 3 which will be typescript native :-)

Comment: @antonK , when you face a specific problem you can find a lot of my socials in my bio, you may also contact me directly :-D

Comment: Here's the API doc for provide/inject in vee-validate https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/concepts/injections.html#injecting-parent-validator

Answer (score 4):

For plain Vuejs i use:

```
inject: ['$validator'],
```

in the child,

and:

```
provide() {
   return {
     $validator: this.$validator,
   };
},
```

in the parent.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a different validator library. I haven't heard of vee-validate, but it looks neat and I might switch since it supports Vue 2.0 whereas vue-validator does not right now. They look pretty similar in concepts though.

Assuming you're not using Vuex and this is a small app, you could use a computed property to grab the validation status of each of the children:

Parent:

```
isValid: function () { 
    for (var i = 0; i < this.$children.length; i++) {
      if (this.$children[i].hasOwnProperty('isValid') && !this.$children[i].isValid) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  }
```

Child:

```
  isValid: function () {
    return this.$vueValidator.valid
  }
```

If you have a child that you don't want to be validated just don't give it an `isValid` computed property.

You could also `$emit` an event from a child when they change states from invalid -> valid or valid -> invalid to tell the parent.

Answer (score 3):

In my case what I do is that I that I disable `vee-validate` injection:

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate, { inject: false });
```

> This will make the plugin stop instantiating a new validator scope for each component instance,
>   excluding the root instance.

And in the parent component i get a new validator instance which i'll share with the desired childs:

```
export default {
  $_veeValidate: {
      validator: 'new' // Determines how the component get its validator instance
                       // 'new' means it will always instantiate its own validator instance
  },
  ......
```

In the child component i inject that parent's validator instance:

```
export default {
    // This will make the component inherit it's parent's validator scope,
    // thus sharing all errors and validation state. Meaning it has access
    // to the same errors and fields computed properties as well.
    inject: ['$validator'],
    ...........
```

Resource: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/concepts/components.html

Answer (score 0):

I had to use a promise to check validation before submitting form.

Code below from @ChalkyJoe original question

```
module.exports = {
  methods: {
    submitForm() {
      //this.$validator.validateAll();
      this.$validator.validateAll().then((result)=>{
          if(!result){
            error();
          }
          submit();
      })
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      email: '',
      confirm_email: ''
    };
  },
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.