# vee-validate error object - _vm.errors is undefined

Tags: vue-component, vue.js

This is my .vue component file in which I wasn't to use `Vue.use()` to install `vee-validate` validation package. The module, as mentioned in the docs, will inject an `errors` object to the `data` object.

But I do get the error `_vm.errors is undefined`. I'm not sure if I'm instantiating it properly.

Also, will `import Vue from 'Vue'` and `Vue.use(VeeValidate)` "use" vee-validate for only this component?(which is what I want it to do).

```
<template>
<input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" v-model="player.name" v-validate data-vv-rules="alpha|min:2|max:50" :class="{'input': true, 'is-danger': errors.has('name') }">
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'Vue';
import VeeValidate from 'vee-validate';
Vue.use(VeeValidate);

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // errors: '',
      showForm: false,
      player: null
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: which version of vue and vee-validate you are using?

Comment: Vue is `2.1.0` and vee-validate is `2.0.0-beta.17`

Comment: The code seems correct, can you reproduce this on jsfiddle?

Comment: @saurabh I can't seem to reproduce it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/donnyjeremiah/0aykrpp3/) . It does work fine. I use it on via the vue-cli 'webpack-simple' bootstrap.

Answer (score 2):

I had a sort alike issue but I am using these versions:

"vee-validate": "^2.0.0-rc.21",
"vue": "^2.5.2",

and in that case you can access the errors collection using: this.$validator.error

see specs off vee-validate:

*http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/api.html#error-bag* (404!)

NEW LINK:
http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v2/api/errorbag.html

scroll down and you see this:

*Validator*

*The validator is injected to the Vue instance as $validator automatically. However it is also a standalone class and can be used separately for programmatically validating values. The constructor can optionally take an object to map each field name to a set of validations.*

Comment: 404 on the link.

Comment: @Jordan : new link given