# Vee-validate independently validate components from parent without EventBus

Tags: javascript, validation, vue.js, vee-validate

I would like to be able to validate all the components (with multiple fields) in my form independently from eachother using Vee-validate.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41022935/validate-child-input-components-on-submit-with-vee-validate) topic. However, the solutions have all components be validated at the same time. I've tried using an EventBus (unsuccesfully) and I would prefer staying away from it.

I have multi step form which should validate the current step before clicking 'continue'. Example:

```
-- Step 1
---- <component-one /> == component with fields 
---- (next button) <-- validate content 1. If valid, go to step 2
-- Step 2
---- <component-two /> == component with fields
---- (next button) <-- validate content 2. If valid, go to step 2
-- Step 3
---- <component-three/> == component with fields
---- (next button) <-- validate content 3. If valid, go to step 3
```

My issue is that I have to call `this.validator` on component level to be able to validate the component. The continue button, however, lives on the parent level. I cannot create one shared `$validator` because then all steps have to be valid in order to continue (which is impossible)/

Comment: You can declare ref at component and use it to parent using this.$refs.[validate method]

Comment: On what element should I declare the ref?

Comment: this all next buttons are same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vee-validate has the concept of "scopes", so I think the trick would be to add `data-vv-scope="step1"` to each form element in `component-one`.  Then when you go to validate in the step 1 "next" button, you'd do `this.$validators.validateAll('step1')`.

If each component has it's own form, you can put the `data-vv-scope` attribute at the form level and it will apply to all the elements inside it.

See [this example](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/examples/scopes.html) for details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, defining the scope on child component level doesn't allow me to validate on parent level, right? I tried it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Frank - it does if you [inject the parent validator](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/concepts/injections.html#injecting-parent-validator)...

Comment: I've set inject to false in `Vue.use(VeeValidate)`, created a new validator in my parent component, used inject in my child component, set a scope on the form tag in my child component and called `this.$validator.validateAll('scope-name')` from the parent.  What could I might do wrong?

Comment: Looks like it does work (in a separate codepen). Prob an issue with the rest of my project. **Edit**: working example for future visitors https://codesandbox.io/s/k359r61j0v

Comment: If you want to show errors on the scoped fields, then you need to use syntax like `errors.first('scopename.fieldname')`. Note the `scopename.` prefix. https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/1311